# Preview in hierarchy viewer is different from what is actually on the screen

Tags: android, layout, view, hierarchyviewer

I'm trying to create a menu that can be pulled from the bottom margin of my application, i've done this by creating a custom view overriding a RelativeLayout, this the xml of the relativelayout that i inflate:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="#77F5F1" >
</FrameLayout>
```

And there's the code of the custom layout:

```
public class BottomMenuStack extends RelativeLayout {
private static final int ACCEPTABLE_TOUCH_OFFSET = 70;
private boolean firstTime = true;
private int closedY;
private View arrowView;
private boolean arrowShowing = true;
private boolean moving = false;
private View contentView;
private View mainView;
private boolean contentShowing = false;
private ObjectAnimator showArrowAnimation, hideArrowAnimation, showAnimation, hideAnimation;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private float openedY, lastDistance;

public BottomMenuStack(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public BottomMenuStack(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_menu, this, true);
    arrowView = findViewById(R.id.arrow);
    contentView = findViewById(R.id.content);
    mainView = (View) arrowView.getParent();
    //   Creates a DestureDetector, to handle the scroll, fling and down events
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new gestureListener());
    gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
    //       Initialize the animations
    hideArrowAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(contentView, "top", 0).setDuration(500);
    showArrowAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(contentView, "top", 0).setDuration(500);
    hideAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mainView, "translationY", 0).setDuration(500);
    showAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mainView, "translationY", 0).setDuration(500);
    showAnimation.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            hideArrow();
        }

        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mainView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 2 * (((View) mainView.getParent()).getHeight() / 3);
        mainView.setLayoutParams(params);
        closedY = mainView.getHeight() - arrowView.getHeight();
        openedY = closedY / 3;
        mainView.setTranslationY(closedY);
        postInvalidate();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean gestureDetectorRes = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (moving && (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {

        if (lastDistance < 0) {
            hideContent();
        } else {
            showContent();
        }
        moving = false;
        return true;
    }
    return gestureDetectorRes;
}

public boolean isTouchAcceptable(float x, float y) {
    if (arrowShowing) {
        if (x > arrowView.getLeft() && x < arrowView.getRight())
            if (y > arrowView.getTop() + mainView.getY() && y < (arrowView.getTop() + mainView.getY() + arrowView.getHeight()))
                return true;
    } else {
        if (y > (mainView.getY() - ACCEPTABLE_TOUCH_OFFSET) && y < (mainView.getY() + ACCEPTABLE_TOUCH_OFFSET))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void toggleContent() {
    if (contentShowing)
        hideContent();
    else
        showContent();
}

public void hideContent() {
    if (contentShowing) {
        cancelScrollAnimations();
        hideAnimation.setFloatValues(mainView.getY(), closedY);
        hideAnimation.start();
        contentShowing = false;
    }
}

public void showContent() {
    if (!contentShowing) {
        cancelScrollAnimations();
        showAnimation.setFloatValues(mainView.getTranslationY(), openedY);
        showAnimation.start();
        contentShowing = true;
    } else if (!showAnimation.isRunning()) {
        hideArrow();
    }

}

public void toggleArrow() {
    if (arrowShowing)
        hideArrow();
    else
        showArrow();
}

public void showArrow() {
    if (!arrowShowing) {
        cancelArrowAnimations();
        showArrowAnimation.setIntValues(contentView.getTop(), arrowView.getHeight());
        showArrowAnimation.start();
        arrowShowing = true;
    }
}

public void hideArrow() {
    if (arrowShowing) {

        cancelArrowAnimations();
        hideArrowAnimation.setIntValues(contentView.getTop(), 0);
        hideArrowAnimation.start();
        arrowShowing = false;
    }
}

private void cancelScrollAnimations() {
    if (showAnimation != null)
        showAnimation.cancel();
    if (hideAnimation != null)
        hideAnimation.cancel();
}

private void cancelArrowAnimations() {
    if (showArrowAnimation != null)
        showArrowAnimation.cancel();
    if (hideArrowAnimation != null)
        hideArrowAnimation.cancel();
}

private class gestureListener implements OnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        if (isTouchAcceptable(e.getX(), e.getY())) {
            showArrow();
            moving = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (moving) {
            if (velocityY > 0)
                hideContent();
            else
                showContent();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        float y = e2.getY();
        if (moving) {
            lastDistance = distanceY;
            if (y < closedY && y > openedY)
                mainView.setTranslationY(y);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

}

    }
```

The problem is that , whenever I try to debug this layout on the hierarchy  viewer (while running the app on the  emulator) I see the views in a completely different position than they actually see on the screen, here's some screenshots to explain the situation better:
[Hierarchy Viewer screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/screenshottzq.png)
[Emulator screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/androidjh.png/)
In these screenshots is possible to see the arrow, that in the the screenshot from the emulator appears above the bottom border of the screen, according to the Hierarchy Viewer is right below  the upper margin, how is it possible? what I'm  doing wrong in moving the views?
Triggering the animations, making the views moving on the screen of the emulator, makes no change in the Hierarchy Viewer preview.